# Elm I need whitespace, but got stuck on what looks like a new declaration

Tags: elm

I just start to try elm and I'm stuck on a basic issue.

Here is my code:

```
add : Int -> Int -> Int
add x y =
  x + y

add 3 4
```

I try to run it in the browser with `elm reactor` but I got this issue.

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
-- SYNTAX PROBLEM ---------------------------------------------------- hello.elm

I need whitespace, but got stuck on what looks like a new declaration. You are
either missing some stuff in the declaration above or just need to add some
spaces here:


I am looking for one of the following things:

    whitespace
```

I search the documentation but I don't find error in my code

Edit: I don't have any error if I remove the `add 3 4`

Comment: I am just having this and it is bloody confusing. No line number, nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run this in the browser you'll need a `main` method that has type `Graphics.Element`, `Html.Html`, `Signal Graphics.Element`, or `Signal Html.Html`. The easiest is just to use `Graphics.Element.show` which with "show" anything as a string.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)

add : Int -> Int -> Int
add x y =
  x + y

main = show (add 3 4)
```

If you just want to try the code out without making a runnable Elm module, you can also use the repl

```
:~ % elm repl
---- elm repl 0.16.0 -----------------------------------------------------------
 :help for help, :exit to exit, more at <https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> add x y = x + y
<function> : number -> number -> number
> add 3 4
7 : number
>
```